# jQuery: Two progress bars inside one div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui

How can I draw two or more jQuery progressbar with diffrent values inside the same `div`?

I need to draw two progress bars in a single `div`, this means I can give only one `id` to the function that creates `progressBar`.

Currently my function is:

```
function drawbar(no,id_of_div) 
{
                 $(id_of_div).progressbar({ value:no });
                 $(id_of_div).css({background: '#99FF66'}); 
 }
```

I want a function that will also take a value for a second progress bar which should be drawn inside the same `div`.

Something like:

```
function drawbar(value_for_first , value_for_second ,id_of_div)
{
---------
------
}
```

Can any body help me?

Comment: Will it accept an array instead of a single DIV id? If not, this is a good reason to write your own progress bar in Javascript and not rely on Jquery :)

Comment: @jayp: What is this, random jQuery abuse day? ;-) (Besides, it's jQuery UI, not jQuery.) It makes perfect sense for a progress bar widget to fill the container you give it. You need two in that container? Subdivide the container.

Comment: Ha, yes it is, didn't you know?! I just think there are vast amounts of people who have no JS knowledge outside of Jquery, you can learn a lot by implementing simple things like that yourself. Jquery is great for convenience and compatability, but not at the expense of learning how Javascript works properly.

Comment: @jayp: :-) Agreed it's very important to understand JavaScript, the language, as distinct from jQuery, the library, and also as distinct from web browsers, the environment most (but not all) people use JavaScript in. Also best to have at least some knowledge of the DOM. Even if you're always using jQuery to manipulate it, it still helps to have some idea what you're manipulating.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're going to have to put divs within the div, since it looks like the jQuery UI progressbar fills its target element. E.g.:

```
function drawbar(value_for_first, value_for_second, id_of_div) {
    var target = $("#" + id_of_div);
    $("<div>").appendTo(target).progressbar({value: value_for_first});;
    $("<div>").appendTo(target).progressbar({value: value_for_second});
}
```

[Live example](http://jsbin.com/urufaf)

They may need `height`, if you're not doing that with CSS (e.g., `css("height", "50%")`). (I haven't used the jQuery UI progress bar.)

If you're *updating* them with the same function, the we'd want to allow for them possibly already being there:

```
function drawbar(value_for_first, value_for_second, id_of_div) {
    var target = $("#" + id_of_div),
        first  = target.find(".first"),
        second = target.find(".second");
    if (!first[0]) {
        first  = $("<div>").addClass("first").appendTo(target);
        second = $("<div>").addClass("second").appendTo(target);
    }
    first.progressbar({value: value_for_first});
    second.progressbar({value: value_for_second});
}
```

[Live example](http://jsbin.com/urufaf/2) - note that it shows initial values, then pauses a second, then updates them

Comment: thanx T.J. for your help ! subdividing the div works correctly !!!

but the problem is that i am actually creating progressbar vertically... with the help of this [link](http://forum.jquery.com/topic/verical-progress-bar) so , though i got two progress bars they are not working as expected.. i mean two vertical progressbar side to each other

Comment: @SauB: Good deal, glad that helped. :-) For the vertical, you probably just need to muck about with the styling of the divs.

Comment: @ T.J. messing with styling is not working for me dude. bcoz Progress bars gets draw in one on one manner.... i want them one next to another.

Comment: @SauB: Doing it vertically is sufficiently removed from your original question I think you're safe asking a new question: "How do I get two vertical jQuery UI progress bars next to each other?" Perhaps someone else has studied the link you posted above. Good luck,